# Connecting two specific points in a map

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this we have a map with data points:

Load data:

```
countries <- structure(list(country = structure(c(5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 
11L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 9L, 12L, 2L), .Label = c("Australia", "China", 
"France", "Georgia", "India", "Ireland", "Malaysia", "Poland", 
"Qatar", "Singapore", "South Africa", "Spain", "USA"), class = "factor"), 
    Latitude = c(20.593684, 53.142367, 46.227638, 32.165622, 
    1.352083, 51.919438, -30.559482, 4.210484, -25.274398, 37.09024, 
    25.354826, 40.463667, 35.86166), Longitude = c(78.96288, 
    -7.692054, 2.213749, -82.900075, 103.819836, 19.145136, 22.937506, 
    101.975766, 133.775136, -95.712891, 51.183884, -3.74922, 
    104.195397), Value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("country", "Latitude", "Longitude", 
"Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Code for map plot using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44345405/8088458):

```
library(maps)
 library(ggplot2)
 base_world <- map_data("world")
p <- ggplot() + 
   geom_polygon(data=base_world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
   geom_point(data=countries, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, colour="blue"), size=5, alpha=I(0.7))
```

I try to connect to points. Example I want to connect:
Spain - China
USA - Spain

What I have until now is this:

```
p + geom_line(data=countries, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), color="black", size=1)
```

and this connects all points in the map. Is it possible to connect only specific values and show in the data point in the map the number of value column?

Also this is what I tried for number labels in every point (Value)

```
p + geom_text(aes(label=countries$Value),hjust=0, vjust=0, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude))
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

Example of the list with more than two points (every row is a different connection):

```
("USA", "Spain","China")
("Australia", "Poland")
```

Comment: `p + geom_line(data=countries[countries$country %in% c("USA", "Spain","China"),],   aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), color="green", size=1) ` will connect the countries

Comment: @Henry thank you. Just a sub question and if Australia - Poland was another pair of connected points how could I add the to list? Using something like this c[("USA", "Spain","China"),("Australia", "Poland")]?

Comment: I would do a second + as in `p + geom_line(data=countries[countries$country %in% c("USA", "Spain","China"),], aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), color="green", size=1)  + geom_line(data=countries[countries$country %in% c("Australia", "Poland"),], aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), color="green", size=1)` though there may be a better way

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/rafapereirabr/flow-map-in-r-ggplot) you will find a simple step-by-step code that shows how to create Flow Maps in R using ggplot2

Comment: @Masoud thank you for the link but this is the answer I used first and the code is the dummy code I provide. I have a list with more than 2 points to connect. Please see the comments above. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a subset based on the points you want to be connected;

```
link1 <- countries[countries$country %in% c("USA", "Spain","China"), ]
link2 <- countries[countries$country %in% c("Australia", "Poland"), ]

base_world <- map_data("world")
p <- ggplot() + 
      geom_polygon(data=base_world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
      geom_line(data=link1, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), color="red", size=1) +
      geom_line(data=link2, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), color="green", size=1) +
      geom_point(data=countries, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), colour = "cyan", size=5, alpha=I(0.7)) + #set the color outside of `aes`
      theme(text = element_text(size=20), legend.position="none")  #remove the legend
```

and your plot would look like:

`> p`

[image: MAP-ggplot2-worldmap-connections-p]

You may need to play around a little bit for formatting issues.